# How to modify javascript captch to use it in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, captcha

I am doing project in extjs. I am designing registration form with captcha code check. I didnt found anything for doing captcha directly in extjs. So i am trying to create captcha code using javascript and want to integrate this javascript captcha in extjs. I have javascript captcha code as-

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
     <head>
     <title>BotBoot</title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
      var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
      var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
      var c = a + b
      function DrawBotBoot()
     {
        document.write("What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? ");
        document.write("<input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2'   size='2'/>");
     }    
     function ValidBotBoot(){
     var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
     if (d == c) return true;        
     return false;
     }
     </script>


    </head>
    <body>

    Are you human?<br />

    <script type="text/javascript">DrawBotBoot()</script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Check" onclick="alert(ValidBotBoot());"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

To integrate this javascript into extjs,,i had created separate Captcha.js file as=

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.sn.user.Captcha',   {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.captcha',
initComponent: function(config){
    this.a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    this.b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
},

DrawBotBoot: function(){

},

ValidBotBoot: function(){

}
});
```

And to include it in my registration form, i am using-
     items:[
     {
       xtype:'captcha',
     }]

But i am not getting any output. So how to change javascript functions DrawBotBoot and ValidBotBoot into extjs? What more changes i will need to do to get this captcha in my registration form?   I am very new to extjs.Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I made the code for you. Did not test it but it should work :)

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.sn.user.Captcha',   {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.captcha',

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    initComponent: function(config){
        var me = this;
        me.inputField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
            name: 'BotBootInput',
            fieldLabel: 'BotBootInput'
        });

        me.checkButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Check',
            handler: function(btn){
                alert(me.ValidBotBoot());
            }
        });

        me.DrawBotBoot();

        Ext.apply(me, {
            items: [me.inputField, me.checkButton]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    DrawBotBoot: function(){
        this.a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        this.b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
        this.c = this.a + this.b;
        this.inputField.fieldLabel = "What is "+ this.a + " + " + this.b +"?");
    },

    ValidBotBoot: function(){
        var d = this.inputField.getValue();
        if (d === this.c){ 
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

//instantiate
var captcha = Ext.widget('captcha');
//to renew the captcha use captcha.DrawBotBoot
```

Comment: oops my mistake.. `this` refers to the button at that time. I'll update it :)

Comment: Debug the ValidBotBoot function and watch the variables.

Comment: Actually sir error is at line "var d = this.inputField.getValue();" When i am doing console.log(this.d),its showing as 'undefined'. It means var d is not getting textfields value.

Comment: Is `this.inputField` also undefined?

Comment: no...its showing textfield on view form. But it is not assigning textfields value to var d. So its always giving me false as alert. And console.log(this.d) is giving output as undefined